# Need Top N Row for Large Dataset. Query is taking a long time. How to optimize?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I have two tables (SalesforceTasks and SalesforceContacts) that I am using for a scoring system project. A simple SELECT statement with a ROW_NUMBER() calculation is taking a very long time to run and actually stops querying once it hits a certain number of rows. The query doesn't stop executing, but it stops returning data.

Here is the query in question. It is a very vanilla process, where I need to get the newest date in the SalesforceTasks table and link it to the contact ID in the SalesforceContacts table. The SalesforceTasks table has 2,091,946 rows and the SalesforceContacts table has 446,772 rows.

Here is the query in question:

```
SELECT SC.ID
      ,CASE
       WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 360 AND 1500
       THEN 15
       WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 181 AND 360
       THEN 10
       WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 180
       THEN 5
       ELSE 0    
       END AS Score
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ST.ACCOUNTID ORDER BY ACTIVITYDATE) AS LastCall 
  FROM Salesforce.dbo.SalesforceTasks AS ST
  JOIN Salesforce.dbo.SalesforceContacts AS SC
    ON ST.ACCOUNTID = SC.ACCOUNTID
 WHERE STATUS = 'Completed'
   AND TYPE LIKE 'Call%'
```

What is the best plan of attack here? As stated, the query is taking a very, very long time to run. Is there a better way to get the newest date from the SalesforceTasks table?

Comment: Have you tried the simplest possible query using `select top`? You could get the row numbers by wrapping that in another query. If that's not going to help, you'll need some deep revisions...

Comment: This is part of a CTE that does technically take the TOP N row if the LastCall calculation equals 1.

Comment: Query plan, statistics io output, indexes (related to account id, status, type) and how big percentage of the rows match status and type is something that could help in solving the problem.

Comment: Might want to look at assigning GETDATE() to a variable (let's call it @DateConstant) outside your query and using that @DateConstant instead of multiple GETDATE calls.

Comment: You're also most likely calculating datediff 3 times, since as far as I remember, case doesn't short circuit, so outer apply or something like that might improve it, but that might also be just marginal

Comment: In case of large data amounts, key lookups can be a big issue, so looking into covering indexes might also help

Comment: Label all the columns for the tables they come from

Answer (score 1):

You could try breaking the statement down in to a 2 step process.

First filter records into `#temp` table and get the `datediff` without the `CASE`:

```
SELECT SC.ID
      ,DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) AS ScoreDiff
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ST.ACCOUNTID ORDER BY ACTIVITYDATE) AS LastCall 
INTO #TEMP
FROM Salesforce.dbo.SalesforceTasks AS ST
  JOIN Salesforce.dbo.SalesforceContacts AS SC
    ON ST.ACCOUNTID = SC.ACCOUNTID
WHERE STATUS = 'Completed'
   AND TYPE LIKE 'Call%'
   AND DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE())  BETWEEN 60 AND 1500
```

With the reduced dataset, you then perform the Scoring operation:

```
SELECT Id,
    CASE ScoreDiff
       WHEN BETWEEN 360 AND 1500
       THEN 15
       WHEN BETWEEN 181 AND 360
       THEN 10
       WHEN BETWEEN 60 AND 180
       THEN 5
       ELSE 0    
    END AS Score,
    LastCall
FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

If purpose is just to get latest one then you can try this else need to find out other way

```
SELECT SC.ID,CASE
   WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 360 AND 1500
   THEN 15
   WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 181 AND 360
   THEN 10
   WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 60 AND 180
   THEN 5
   ELSE 0    
   END AS Score,
   SFC.ACTIVITYDATE
FROM Salesforce.dbo.SalesforceTasks AS ST
JOIN Salesforce.dbo.SalesforceContacts AS SC
CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT MAX(SFC.ID) AS SCID,MAX(SFC.ACTIVITYDATE) AS ACTIVITYDATE FROM Salesforce.dbo.SalesforceContacts SFC
               WHERE SFC.ACCOUNTID=SC.ACCOUNTID
               GROUP BY BY SFC.ACCOUNTID
               HAVING MAX(SFC.ID)=  SC.ID               
    )
ON ST.ACCOUNTID = SC.ACCOUNTID
 WHERE STATUS = 'Completed'
   AND TYPE LIKE 'Call%'
   AND DATEDIFF(DD, ST.CREATEDDATE, GETDATE())  BETWEEN 60 AND 1500
```